# How can I detect similarity of names in the same columns

Tags: pandas, string, similarity, fuzzywuzzy

Guys I have a dataset like this:
`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = ['John','gal britt','mona','diana','molly','merry','mony','molla','johnathon','dina'],\
                  columns = ['Name'])
df
```

### `
it gives this output

```
Name
0   John
1   gal britt
2   mona
3   diana
4   molly
5   merry
6   mony
7   molla
8   johnathon
```

---

so I imagine that to get all names across each other and detect the similarity I will use `df.merge(df,how = "cross" )`

The thing is the real data is 40000 rows and performing this will result in a very big dataset which I don't have the memory for.
any algorithm or idea would really help and I'll adjust the logic to my purposes

I tried working with `vaex` instead of pandas to work with this huge amount of data but still I run into the problem of insufficient memory allocation.
In short: I KNOW that this algorithm or way of thinking about such problem is wrong and inefficient.

Comment: What is your desired output? Please can you be more specific abou how you're measuring similarity?

Comment: It's just fuzzywuzzy token_set_ratio.
the first name for example is john will be paired with each name and then the fuzzy logic will be applied on each column

Comment: the thing is my algorithm is inefficient and any other solution/adjustment would be appreciated

Comment: you can use pyspark. This will process the data in chunks. 
Disadvantage: you won't to be able to use python library without compromising the speed. 

Although you can first filter the dataset using simple similarlity logic like len(common_words)/len(union_words)